# Is there a way to get the Mac media buttons (previous, play/pause, next) behavior on Windows?

Tags: windows, mac, audio, keyboard, media

I was wondering if there was a way to imitate a Macbook's media buttons (see image below) on a Windows PC and subsequent keyboard. I've fallen in love with the Mac's media buttons and would love to have the same behavior on my PC.

What I am specifically looking for in its behavior is that I don't have to necessarily be in the correct tab or app for the system to recognize where the audio/video source is coming from, and I can use those media buttons from anywhere (similarly as on a Mac)

I have a keyboard that allows for custom keybinds and macro's, so those options would be acceptable answers too.

[image: Macbook Pro keyboard]

Comment: I've got an old Dell keyboard with media keys right above the function keys, works a treat  on Windows and on my Mac. In other words keyboards with media keys on them are extremely common. But perhaps not ones that use the function keys *as* media keys.

Comment: Turns out my keyboard has a list of "media buttons" that you can assign to keys, so I assigned the same media buttons as in the photo above on my F5-F10 keys and it works as intended :)